# p-forms as multilinear maps

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

I'm studying differential geometry and am learning about differential forms. We have a very intuitive and simple way to understand 1-forms as linear maps on from the tangent space to the base field, defined as $$df(v) = vf$$ where $v$ is a vector field acting on $f$.

Now what my book does not mention and what I cannot seem to make up is how $p>1$ forms fit into this picture as multilinear forms. I know how to apply the exterior derivative and understand the exterior algebra, but it seems there is something missing. For example, for the case of a  2-form $df\wedge dg$, I would expect there to be a map that takes two vector fields and produces a real number. What is this map, both conceptually and syntactically? And how does this generalize to arbitrary p-forms?

Comment: That's right, if $u$ and $v$ are vector fields, then $(df\wedge dg)(u, v) = (uf)(vg) - (ug)(vf),$ maybe divided by $2$ depending on the exact definition of the wedge product. I've always thought of that as a [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Wedge_product) for the wedge product.

Comment: What is the definition of the exterior algebra you are working with? The quotient of the tensor algebra by the ideal generated by $\omega \otimes \omega$ for all tensors $\omega$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll write about the case of a single tangent space $V$, since this question is really about algebra.

In the quotient algebra construction, a form (an element of the exterior algebra) is a coset $[\omega] = \omega + I$, where $\omega$ is a $p$-tensor (multilinear map $V^p \to \mathbb F$) and $I$ is the two-sided ideal of the tensor algebra generated by all symmetric products $\xi \otimes \xi$, $\xi$ any tensor. The wedge product is just the multiplication induced by the tensor product; i.e. $[\alpha] \wedge [\beta] = [\alpha \otimes \beta]$.

Each of these cosets $[\omega]$ contains a unique totally antisymmetric tensor $\bar \omega$; i.e. a multilinear map $\bar\omega : V^p \to \mathbb F$ that changes by the sign of the permutation when you permute the inputs. Thus the exterior algebra (a *quotient* of the tensor algebra) can be naturally identified with the space of totally antisymmetric tensors (a *subspace* of the tensor algebra). This is very convenient for the purposes of differential geometry (it lets differential forms act on vectors), but the quotient definition is often preferred exactly because it gives you the wedge product for free.

Using this identification, we can take the wedge product and let it act on antisymmetric tensors: $\bar\omega \wedge \bar\alpha := \overline{\omega \wedge \alpha}$.
The wedge product of two one-forms then turns out to be $ \alpha \wedge \beta = \frac12 \left( \alpha \otimes \beta - \beta \otimes \alpha \right)$; i.e. $$(\alpha \wedge \beta)(u,v) = \frac12 \left( \alpha(u) \beta(v) - \beta(u) \alpha(v) \right).$$

Many authors define the wedge product on antisymmetric tensors without the factor of $\frac12$ - doing this makes the formulas simple, but makes the relationship back to the quotient algebra less natural.

In general the wedge product of $p$ $1$-forms $\theta_i$ turns out to be (as you'd expect) the total antisymmetrization of their tensor product:

$$ (\theta_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta_p)(u_1, \ldots, u_p) = \frac1{p!}\det_{ij} (\theta_i(u_j)) = \frac1{p!} \sum_{\sigma} \theta_1 (u_{\sigma(1)}) \cdots \theta_p (u_{\sigma(p)})$$ where the sum is over all permutations of $\{ 1 , \ldots,  p \}$. (Those other authors I mentioned would omit the $1/p!$ term.)

If you want you can use this to derive the expression for the wedge product of two forms of arbitrary order - it gets even messier. (See e.g. Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* - one of the "other" authors.) Comparing this to our original definition of the wedge product, one can appreciate why the quotient construction is so nice to have.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't understand everything, but I'll try to digest it. I'm only a theoretical physicist, confronted with these issues on a very practical level, and my book seems to be rather superficial.

Comment: @DirkDinther: Ah, so perhaps you've just seen the exterior algebra constructed as "whatever you can generate using 1-forms and the wedge product (which obeys some commutation law)"? The quotient of the tensor algebra is essentially the same thing phrased in a more formal way. If you're familiar with index notation then the practical thing to take away from this is that you can view the wedge product as the antisymmetrization of the tensor product on 1-forms; i.e. $(\alpha \wedge \beta \wedge \gamma)_{ijk} = \alpha_{[i}\beta_{j}\gamma_{k]}$.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but isn't there supposed to be a $sgn(\sigma)$ after the summation symbol in the final equation?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if a $p$-form $\omega:T_pM\times...\times T_pM\rightarrow\mathbb R$, can be written as exterior product of $p$ 1-form such as $\omega=\alpha_1\wedge...\wedge\alpha_p$. And if given vector fields $X_1,...,X_p$, we can explicitly compute 
$$\omega(X_1,...,X_p)=\det\left(\alpha_i(X_j)\right)$$